# Mouse Input Unexplained Behavior Unity3D

Tags: unity, input

`Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0.....6);` - in documentation it says that you can pass, 0, 1, 2 as parameter. [Input.GetMouseButtonDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html). It doesn't accept negative numbers like -1 or numbers 7+. What does 3 4 5 6 do? What input are they calculating? Or can I use these numbers as default for None state? I couldn't find any information about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 is the left mouse button, 1 is the right ,2 is the middle. The rest are there for mice with extra buttons. Like some gaming mice have buttons on the side.
For example using this code :

```
void Update () {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(3))
        {
            Debug.Log(true);
        }
    }
```

and pressing my 4th mouse button I get true in the console.

Comment: Do you know if there is default mouse input like `KeyCode.None`? I don't want to check for numbers in my loop if that is not necessary.

Comment: All I can think of is Input.anyKey. But the GetMouseButton method only accepts integers.

Comment: Also, wanted to add for people who found this question - those who are using Event.current to get what key or mouse button was pressed - buttons 3, 4, aren't going to get any reaction. Event.current.isMouse = false when you press 3 and 4 at least on my mouse and I have no more buttons, so I could not check with 5 and 6. So this is not a way to bind those buttons inside the game by Event.current.button. For 0, 1, 2 it's working nice.